# how to get count ArrayList in dictionary wpf c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, count

I want to get count of list but my list is in dictionary.

```
Dictionary < string,  ArrayList > ();

wording["utterance"+x].Count; // this gives me count for items in dictionary.
```

What I want to know is:

- how many items I are there in my ArrayList?
- how to refer to the elements in the list?

Comment: **wording["utterance"+x].Count; => this gives me count for items in dictionary.** if `wording` is your dictionary this would give you the number of elements in the ArrayList associated with this key. The number of elements (KeyValuePair) in the dictionary itself would be `wording.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how many items I are there in my ArrayList?

```
(wording["utterance"+x] as ArrayList).Count; // gives count of items in ArrayList
```

> how to refer to the elements in the list?

```
wording["Actual Key"][<numeric index of item number>; // wording["utterance"+x][0] in your case for first item in arraylist
```

Answer (score 1):

You could of course do:

```
ArrayList al = wording["key"];
int count = al.Count;
```

I'm curious why your initial code wouldn't work though, unless Linq extensions are interfering.

I would go with Amicable's suggestion of `List<T>` over `ArrayList` though.

Answer (score 0):

***how many items I are there in my ArrayList?***

The code you gave should do just that:

```
// number of items in the ArrayList at key "utterance" + x
wording["utterance"+x].Count;
```

***how to refer to the elements in the list?***

You can refer to them by index:

```
// get the 4th item in the list at key "key"
object myObject = wording["key"][3];
```

Or you can iterate over them:

```
foreach (object item in wording["key"])
   DoSomething(item);
```

To summarize, `wording` is a `Dictionary` that stores `ArrayList`s by a `string` key. You can retrieve a particular `ArrayList` by indexing with the appropriate `string` key for that `ArrayList`.

```
wording // evaluates to Dictionary<string, ArrayList>
wording["sometext"] // evaluates to ArrayList
```

Note that the latter will throw an exception if you have not already placed an `ArrayList` at that key.